# Simple Web Worker not working in SvelteKit on Firefox 106.0.5

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, svelte, sveltekit

Inside my main file, I have

```
const loadWorker = async () => {
        const SyncWorker = await import("$lib/canvas.worker?worker");
        syncWorker = new SyncWorker.default();

        syncWorker?.postMessage({});
    };
```

Then in my unmount I have

```
onMount(() => {
        console.log("Canvas: mounted");
        loadWorker();
});
```

Then in my canvas.worker.ts file, I have a simple

```
onmessage = () => {
    console.log("Hello from the worker!");
};

export {};
```

This message prints successfully in Chrome, but in firefox all I get is

> **SyntaxError:** import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Is this because the worker is stored on my local system, and maybe there's a special flag to allow loading of system files as workers (as that seems it may be a security concern)? Firefox docs say that my browser should support workers.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I should've read the documentation better.

> service workers only work in the production build, not in development.
> To test it locally, use **vite preview**
>
> https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/service-workers

Or in my case, "npm run build && npm run preview" worked.

Comment: Saved me some minor "embarrassment," thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the build script with nodemon.

> npm install -D nodemon

And add a new script like this in your package.json

> "sw-dev": "nodemon --watch src --ext * --exec "npm run build && npm run preview""

This is only a workaround if you want to development on unsupported browsers, not a good solution. Otherwise just stick to chrome-based browsers.

Answer (score 0):

SvelteKit's Service Worker support in dev mode require a browser that supports modules as workers. I don't have any trouble with it working on Chromium-based browsers, but Firefox has lagged way behind on it. That is the reason I switched to Vivaldi.

Also, things may have changed since this question was asked, but SvelteKit allows you to create a service worker simply by placing it in `src/service-worker.js` or `src/service-worker.ts`. It will manage it for you. It is a bit slow to replace the old version when you make changes in development. But that might be at least partially the fault of the browser. I work around it by clearing site data manually because I'm impatient. Browsers should pull in new versions automatically in time.